# How to get the "document" in vscode webview provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, webview

I am developing an extension for vscode. I try to use React for the interface. Unfortunately I can't insert my react root component into the HTML of the webview.

I have tried several approaches but I can't get any of them to work for me.

This is the code of my webview provider:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { UtilityService as Us } from "../../domain/services/util.service";
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

export class SeekerSidebarViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  public static readonly viewType = "seeker.sidebarView";
  private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext<unknown>,
    token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ): void | Thenable<void> {
    this._view = webviewView;
    webviewView.webview.options = { enableScripts: true };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);

    this.loadReact();
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri,
        "src\\infraestructure\\views\\collections\\collections.tsx"
      )
    );

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Seekers</title>
        </head>
        <body>    
            
            ${this.loadReact()}
            <script/>
        </body>
        </html>`;
  }
  // <script nonce="${Us.getNonce()}" src="${scriptUri}">

  private loadReact() {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "seekerSideBar";

    // Render your React component instead
    const root = createRoot(div);
    flushSync(() => {
      root.render(<h1>Hello, world </h1>);
    });
    return div.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

But i get the following errors:

```
document is not defined: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at SeekerSidebarViewProvider.loadReact (c:\workspace\adeso-seeker\dist\extension.js:49:21)
    at SeekerSidebarViewProvider._getHtmlForWebview (c:\workspace\adeso-seeker\dist\extension.js:42:20)
    at SeekerSidebarViewProvider.resolveWebviewView (c:\workspace\adeso-seeker\dist\extension.js:28:41)
    at g.$resolveWebviewView (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:111:41422)
    at i.N (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:10813)
    at i.M (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:10579)
    at i.H (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:9621)
    at i.G (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:8875)
    at n.value (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:7566)
    at m.w (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1902)
    at m.fire (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2119)
    at w.fire (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:79:13940)
    at n.value (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:135:7901)
    at m.w (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1902)
    at m.fire (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2119)
    at w.fire (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:79:13940)
    at MessagePortMain.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:135:6181)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:367)
    at Object.topLevelDomainCallback (node:domain:161:15)
    at Object.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:24)

Webview fatal error: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.
```

What can i do to make the `document` reference works in the vscode webview provider?

Comment: i just fixed it,

Comment: how did you fix it

Answer (score 0):

VSC API does not have a `document` object.

Add the JavaScript of `loadReact()` inside the HTML returned from `_getHtmlForWebview()`.

Get it to work as a standalone HTML page in a browser and use that to return from `_getHtmlForWebview()`.